# Laravel Spatie Medialibrary: upload multiple images through REST API

Tags: laravel

I'm using the [Spatie MediaLibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) library in a Laravel application. I want to upload 0 or more photos to my app via a REST API.

I can get it to work when the `photo` attribute contains 1 file

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'          =>      'required',
        'slug'          =>      'required',
        'description'   =>      'required',
        'price'         =>      'required|integer',
        'photo'         =>      'nullable|file'
    ]);
    $listing =  Listing::Create([
        'user_id'       =>      auth('api')->user()->id,
        'name'          =>      $request->name,
        'slug'          =>      $request->slug,
        'description'   =>      $request->description,
        'price'         =>      $request->price,
    ]);
    // stores the photo
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $listing->addMediaFromRequest('photo')->toMediaCollection('photos');
    }
    return new ListingResource($listing);
}
```

The postman request looks as follows:
[image]

I know want to change the code so it can handle multiple photos in the request. I'm using the following code in the controller above to do so:

```php
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
   foreach ($request->input('photo', []) as $photo) {
       $listing->addMediaFromRequest('photo')->toMediaCollection('photos');
   }
}
```

and I have changed the attribute to `photos[]` instead of `photo`.

[image]

The code never goes into the foreach loop even.

Anyone has a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried like this photo[0] -> file1, photo[1] -> file2 in postman?

Comment: Can you provide what you get when do `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: `$request->input()` doesn't work for files; you probably need to use `$request->file()`, `foreach($request->file('photo') AS $photo){ ... }`. Also, make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, or if this is done via AJAX, you're using `PostData`.

Comment: @Tim: via Postman the enctype is set automatically if you select 'file'. The sueestion of $request->file() does not work.

Comment: @mare96: the output of dd() is not very readable as this is only a REST API, no Blade views whatsever.

Comment: I know but you should have there your images, and with `$request->all()` you will have only your data so if you can provide it from image or whatever.

Comment: Agree. I checked the dd() output and the images are there. I found a solution in the meantime, will post soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the Spatie Medialibrary has a function called `addMultipleMediaFromRequest`. The full code is now

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate([
        'name'          =>      'required',
        'slug'          =>      'required',
        'description'   =>      'required',
        'price'         =>      'required|integer',
        'photo'         =>      'nullable'
    ]);

    $listing =  Listing::Create([
        'user_id'       =>      auth('api')->user()->id,
        'name'          =>      $request->name,
        'slug'          =>      $request->slug,
        'description'   =>      $request->description,
        'price'         =>      $request->price,
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $fileAdders = $listing->addMultipleMediaFromRequest(['photo'])
            ->each(function ($fileAdder) {
                $fileAdder->toMediaCollection('photos');
            });
    }

    return new ListingResource($listing);
}
```

In Postman, I'm calling it as follows:
[image]

[documentation reference](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/api/adding-files#addmultiplemediafromrequest)

Comment: don't why but this method uploads only one file for me

Comment: For someone facing @YassineQoraiche problem, double-check if you are sending multiple files in the array from the front end. In my case, appending files in the front end was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upload multiple files like this:

```
if($request->file('photos')) {
    foreach ($request->file('photos') as $photo) {
        $post->addMedia($photo)->toMediaCollection('post');
    }
}
```

Check this out:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/227#issuecomment-220794240

Answer (score 0):

**This code is working for me.**

### View

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple />
```

### ListingController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
                    $fileAdders = $listing->addMultipleMediaFromRequest(['photo'])
                        ->each(function ($fileAdder) {
                            $fileAdder->toMediaCollection('photos');
                        });
                }
}
```